# PHP session variables lost when using them on other variables

Tags: php, variables, session

I have this PHP script that starts a session and creates its variables. Here's the code snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!is_array($_SESSION['cart'])) $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
$id = 10;
$_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array( 'cod' => 'ABC', 'price' => '80', 'status' => 'active' );
header('Location: http://www.example.com/checkout.php');
?>
```

When I use **print_r** to output the $_SESSION array, I get this:

```
Array (
    [cart] => Array (
        [136] => Array (
            [cod] => ABC
            [price] => 80
            [status] => active
        )
    )
)
```

This works great: the user session is created and all of its variables are nicely set up and after that the user is redirected to que checkout page.

But there is a problem: when the user reaches que checkout page, everything looks fine. See the code snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

The output of the **print_r** above is exactly what we've seen before: and Array filled with other Arrays. Great! But here starts the weird part: when I use the any session variable to be set as a value of another variable, the session data is lost. Check it out:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
foreach ($cart as $key => $data) : // if I use foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $data) will be the same thing
    /*** Do stuff here ***/
endforeach;
?>
```

The output of the **print_r** above is:

```
Array (
    [cart] => Array (
        [cod] => ABC
        [price] => 80
        [status] => active
    )
)
```

In fact if I just output variable values without using them in the script, everything is ok. But when I use a variable somewhere in my script (even after putting the **print_r** snippet) the session variable lost some of its data.

I've tried to serialize the `$_SESSION['cart']` variable, but it's very annoying to unserialize it every time I want to get its values.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you by any chance have `register_globals` on? That might explain some weird overwriting... If you have, disable it & test again.

Comment: Yes! You're right! After 8 hours trying to solve this, I always got the answer from you @Wrikken! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem while processing the Do Stuff Here Portion in foreach, you can check this while processing:

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $data)
{
if(is_array($data)){}
}
```